# Notify icon does not show in tray C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

why does my notification icon does not show in system tray when i launch my windows form?
Here is what i am doing.
I have a windows service which launches my tray application which is a windows form application (I am using impersonation to launch that application in current user's context).
In tray application i am launching a form which contains notify icon. 

The problem here is that the notify icon some times does not appear in system tray and i am unable to find out why.

In the OnLoad method of the form i am setting form's visible property to false.
Also i am doing some remoting service calls (like ipc). Is that a problem?

How do i make my notify icon to appear always in system tray?
EDIT: Here is the code for OnLoad function

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    //Get some value from registry
    CheckForStealthMode();
    GetLoginType();
    bool GetProbeStatus = false;
    ServiceActivityInterface remoteMethods = null;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            remoteMethods = (ServiceActivityInterface)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ServiceActivityInterface), "tcp://localhost:18800/ServiceRemoting);
            ProbeStatus = remoteMethods.GetProbeStatus();
            GetProbeStatus = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            GetProbeStatus = false;
            log.Error("Exception while getting the status of Probe:" + exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            remoteMethods = null;
            if (!GetProbeStatus) 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                log.Debug("Retrying to get the probe status.");
            }
        }
    } while (!GetProbeStatus);  
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code in your OnLoad method (for a start)?

Comment: Is it just the tray icon that is not showing up, or is anything else failing to run as expected? Have you checked the Windows event viewer to see if there is anything reported in the application event logs (or even the security logs)?

Comment: @ Ben Scott i ve posted the code in the question.

Comment: @Jason Down Yes only tray icon not showing up all other functions working as expected.

Comment: On a side note I would suggest it's a bad idea to define most variables with the word 'Get' as when you refer to it, it will read like a method call e.g. GetProbeStatus = true;

Answer (score 0):

For now I would suggest a few breakpoints around the Notify icon code or other conditional statements to find if something isn't being called. Try and find a consistent reproduction in order to help you diagnose what is going on. I have had strange goings on in past of which the most confusin was one linked to a timed event

I would also suggest (and this may solve your problem if it does relate the Thread.Sleep method that this is not ideal. The user just gets a frozen UI. Use one of the timer classes and pick up the tick or elapsed event so the user can carry on but you still get the delay your after.

Comment: Hm, ok I would still go down the breakpoint view, the main goal with or without these it to establish a reproduction you can repeat with the same result. It may be a bug out of your control for which you need a hack or something in the wrong order, or just an issue in the code. Breakpoints are the way I normally try and establish this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `OnLoad` method, you've got a potentially infinite loop that can only execute once every 5 seconds if there is any exeception thrown, with the exception logged then thrown away. When you `Thread.Sleep` you're blocking the UI thread and most likely stopping the notify icon from displaying. I would look at the `Activator.GetObject` or the RPC `GetProbeStatus` calls, and consider moving the RPC code to another thread to avoid blocking the UI.

Comment: Yes you are right the RPC was blocking the UI thread i have moved to new thread. But even after that i was getting the same problem. I just found out temporary solution by setting notify icon's visible property to false and then again to true, weird but works for me.